# How to Determine C Byte Offsets

Tags: c

Hi I have a question from a book that I am confused about in regards to byte offsets, I am learning by myself and am confused. The question is asking:

For the structure declaration

```
struct
{
char *a; //8 byte
short b; //2 bytes
double c; //8 bytes
char d; //1 byte
float e; //4 bytes
char f; /1 byte
long long g; //8 bytes
void *h; //8 bytes 
} foo;
```

suppose it was compiled on a Windows and UNIX machine, where each primitive data type of K bytes must have an offset that is a multiple of K.

A. What are the byte offsets of all the fields in the structure?

B. What is the total size of the structure?

C. Rearrange the fields of the structure to minimize wasted space, and then show the byte offsets and total size for the rearranged structure.

I don't really understand byte offsets, I know we are supposed to get the size of each primitive type and then block them out side by side, since the highest byte is double right so they would all be 8? Help would be appreciated thanks. Also if I just count the size of the primitive types for B. that would not be correct would it?

Comment: `a` is at 0 and is either 4 or 8 bytes wide depending on architecture, let's assume 8 for now. `b` is at 8 and is 2 bytes wide. 8 is a multiple of 2. `c` is 8 bytes wide, what's the next multiple of 8 and so on. When you rearrange them it's best to go from smallest width to largest.

Comment: First thing to do is find out the size of each field in the structure, e.g. using `printf` and `sizeof`. Then [edit] the question and add the size as a comment next to each field. The size of primitive types can be different on different systems, so we need to know the sizes on your system.

Comment: If you do end up running this through a compiler to get the sizes then the [offsetof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) macro would also be helpful.

Comment: I have updated the size thanks for the input but still confused lol

Comment: The size of `a` is incorrect, it is a pointer to char, not a char.

Comment: Assuming all pointers are the same size, then `a` is the same size as `h`, so `a` is 8 bytes.

Comment: harleyquin, "compiled on a Windows and UNIX machine," is the wrong parameter.   It depends on the compiler and options, not the OS.

Comment: Right size of pointer is 8 bytes my mistake. Thanks for all the suggestions and I will try to upvote everyone.

Answer (score 4):

This is an exercise in understanding alignment and struct padding.

On most high-end systems like PC, the CPU has support for efficiently handling things like 32 or 64 bit chunks of data in a single instruction. Most often this require the data to be stored on an *aligned address* for the given type. That is, an address which is evenly divisible by the size of the type.

For example a `uint32_t` may have an alignment requirement of 4 bytes and instructions reading it will require the data to be stored on addresses ending with 0, 4, 8 and so on. Failing to allocate the data on such an address would lead to a *misaligned* access, which depending on system could lead to slower code or even a hardware exception. C doesn't guarantee what will happen if you do misaligned access, it is so-called undefined behavior.

Now when it comes to structs in C, there is a requirement that the members must be allocated in the order specified by the programmer, starting with the first member at the lowest address. The compiler is *not* allowed to re-order them or allocate them as it pleases, as it would be allowed to do with plain local variables.

But in order to allocate members in the order specified and still sate the alignment requirements of each member's type for the given system, a compiler is allowed to insert so-called *padding bytes* anywhere inside the struct, except at the very top of it, which is guaranteed to be aligned. Basically filling up extra dummy bytes between members to ensure that each member is aligned.

I hacked together a little program to display the contents of your struct (source [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Pf7Ta8vha)). How it works and what it does isn't important, what's important is the output gained from executing it, in this case with gcc on x86_64 Linux:

```
     char* a  size: 8   theo offs:  0   real offs:  0
     short b  size: 2   theo offs:  8   real offs:  8
    double c  size: 8   theo offs: 10   real offs: 16
      char d  size: 1   theo offs: 18   real offs: 24
     float e  size: 4   theo offs: 19   real offs: 28
      char f  size: 1   theo offs: 23   real offs: 32
 long long g  size: 8   theo offs: 24   real offs: 40
     void* h  size: 8   theo offs: 32   real offs: 48
Theoretical size of foo: 40
Real size of foo: 56
```

Here you see which size each member got on the given system.

"Theo offs" means theoretical offset - the offset that this member would have in the struct on a system with no alignment requirements and no inserted padding.

"Real offs" means the real offset that the compiler actually gave this member in memory, based on alignment requirements.

Similarly, you can see the theoretical size if the struct had no padding just 100% data, as well as the real size it actually ended up with.

For example the member `c` has an 8 byte alignment requirement so it couldn't be placed at offset 10, because that isn't an 8 byte aligned address. Instead the compiler moved it up to address 16, inserting no less than 6 padding bytes to achieve this.

These padding bytes are wasted space. With more careful planning, we could have placed actual data in those 6 bytes instead. For example other members like `d`, which is just 1 byte with no alignment requirement. So simply by changing the order of `c` and `d`, we would see a pretty drastic change of the total struct size (from 56 to 48 in my example).

Re-ordering these members in the most efficient way is left as an exercise, though a hint is to always place the largest members first, if possible.

Comment: "and still _sate_ the alignment requirements" --> candidate _word of the day_.

Comment: total size is 48 bytes no? char *a fits in 8 bytes, short b becomes 8 bytes with 6 bytes padding total 8, double c is 8 bytes, char d float e and char f are 6 bytes with 2 padding bytes total 8 bytes, long long g is 8 bytes and void *h 8 bytes = 48

Comment: @harleyquin This wasn't calculated by hand but by asking the compiler in the little demo program I linked. As you can see from the table, `d` 1 byte + 3 padding, `e` takes 4 bytes, then `f` 1 byte + no less than 7 padding bytes after it.

Answer (score 2):

> What are the byte offsets of all the fields in the structure?

You can get what are the byte offsets with `offsetof` macro. The offsets are *implementation defined* and expect them to be different depending on platform.

> What is the total size of the structure?

You can get the size with `sizeof`. You should generally expect the size and offsets to be only known after compilation and only by the compiler. The compiler can put as many padding bytes between members as it wants. You only know that the compiler can't rearrange the members, and that the first members starts immediately.

> How to Determine C Byte Offsets

Generally, compile a sample program that would print all the interesting byte offsets and the sizeof of the struct. Then execute the program, and get the information from its output.

> here each primitive data type of K bytes **must** have an offset that is a multiple of K.
>
> Rearrange the fields of the structure to minimize wasted space, and then show the byte offsets and total size for the rearranged structure.

C programming language is nowadays more of a **abstraction** of the underlying hardware. You would write a serialization and deserialization routines from "minimal waste space" to the abstraction that you can use in C:

```
    // the abstract C representation of the data:
    struct foo_s { 
        char a;
        short b;
        double c;
        char d;
        float e;
        char f;
        long long g;
        void *h;
    };
    
    // Note - this code is technically invalid.
    #define GET_MEMBER_SIZE(type, memb)  (sizeof(((type*)0)->(memb)))
    
    // The size of the "minimal waste space" buffer.
    const size_t FOO_SIZE =
       GET_MEMBER_SIZE(struct foo_s, a) +
       GET_MEMBER_SIZE(struct foo_s, b) +
       GET_MEMBER_SIZE(struct foo_s, c) +
       GET_MEMBER_SIZE(struct foo_s, d) +
       GET_MEMBER_SIZE(struct foo_s, e) +
       GET_MEMBER_SIZE(struct foo_s, f) +
       GET_MEMBER_SIZE(struct foo_s, g) +
       GET_MEMBER_SIZE(struct foo_s, h);
    
   // Small wrapper to do memcpy with sizeof and increment the buffer.
   #define BUFFER_WRITE(pnt, var)  do { \
         memcpy(pnt, &var, sizeof(var)); \
         pnt += sizeof(var); \
      } while(0)

    // Convert C abstraction to "minimal waste space" buffer.
    void foo_serialize(char buf[FOO_SIZE], const struct foo_s *t) {
       BUFFER_WRITE(buf, t->a);
       BUFFER_WRITE(buf, t->b);
       BUFFER_WRITE(buf, t->c);
       BUFFER_WRITE(buf, t->d);
       BUFFER_WRITE(buf, t->e);
       BUFFER_WRITE(buf, t->f);
       BUFFER_WRITE(buf, t->g);
       BUFFER_WRITE(buf, t->h);
    }

   #define BUFFER_READ(pnt, dest)  do { \
         memcpy(&dest, pnt, sizeof(dest)); \
         pnt += sizeof(dest); \
      } while(0)

    // Convert from "minimal waste space" to C abstraction.
    void foo_deserialize(struct foo_s *t, const char buf[FOO_SIZE]) {
       BUFFER_READ(buf, t->a);
       BUFFER_READ(buf, t->b);
       BUFFER_READ(buf, t->c);
       BUFFER_READ(buf, t->d);
       BUFFER_READ(buf, t->e);
       BUFFER_READ(buf, t->f);
       BUFFER_READ(buf, t->g);
       BUFFER_READ(buf, t->h);
    }
```

Alternatively, if you *really* want to write with buffers, you would write setters/getters for every member to provide C abstraction:

```
   char foo_get_a(const char buf[FOO_SIZE]) {
        char r;
        memcpy(&r, buf, sizeof(r));
        return r;
   }
   void foo_set_a(char buf[FOO_SIZE], char r) {
        memcpy(buf, &r, sizeof(r));
   }
   short foo_get_b(const char buf[FOO_SIZE]) {
        short r;
        memcpy(&r, buf + sizeof(char), sizeof(r));
        return r;
   }
   void foo_set_b(char buf[FOO_SIZE], short r) {
        memcpy(buf + sizeof(char), &r, sizeof(r));
   }
   // etc. for each member
```

Comment: Aside: `GET_MEMBER_SIZE` could use a _compound literal_ to avoid _technically invalid_ - even if a foolish compiler emits inefficient code.

Answer (score 1):

> Rearrange the fields of the structure to minimize wasted space

To address this one part and expand on [always place the largest members first, if possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73878564/2410359) maxim:

- If pressed to code for *likely* minimize wasted space, consider ordering per *specified minimum* size - or at least the likely minimum size.
- Group members of the same type.
- There is a standard library type call `max_align_t` "which is an object type whose alignment is the greatest fundamental alignment".  `struct/union` order of objects a multiple of this size or more likely makes no difference to minimize wasted space.
- Function pointers may differ in size that object pointers.  If so, function pointers are *usually* larger.
- Integers and pointers have independent sizes.  Avoid assuming too much about comparative sizes.
- Arrays of objects must meet the alignment needs of the first element.
- Common integer types ascend (non-decrease) in size `char, short, int, long, long long, intmax_t`.  Their relationship to `intN_t` is subject to limitations, but not certain.
- Floating point (FP) types ascend in size `float, double, long double`.
- Complex FP are certainly 2x their non-complex size.
- `bool` may be the size of a `char` or `int` or possibly (and rarely) others.
- `size_t`, `ptrdiff_t`, `(u)intptr_t` relate to pointer sizes yet have potential to be wider/narrower then commonly seen.
- `time_t`, `struct tm`, `thrd_t`, ... and other specialize types (aside from characters) tend to meet `max_align_t` requirement, but are not specified as such.
- Bit-fields alignment/packing needs have many considerations.